# Set Inputfields Values with Jquery if Text contains String

Tags: jquery, string, contains, setvalue

I am trying to validate an input text field with jquery.
If the text field contain a value like "24004" or "24005", then other text fields should be changed

```
<input list="listname" id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" value="" required />
```

```
<datalist id="listname">
    <option value="24004 - Name1 - Street1 - Place1">
    <option value="24005 - Name2 - Street2 - Place2">
</datalist>

<input id="textinput2" name="textinput2" type="text" value="" required />

<script>
$( "#textinput" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    if (value *= "24004") {
        $('#textinput2').val("My new value");
    }
    if (value *= "24005") {
        $('#textinput2').val("My new value");
    }
  })
  .keyup();
 */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this.

```
$("#textinput").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value.indexOf("24004") > -1) {
    $('#textinput2').val("My new value");
  }
  if (value.indexOf("24005") > -1) {
    $('#textinput2').val("My new value");
  }
})
```

You could also use `value.includes('24004')` instead of the `indexOf`

**Demo**

```js
$("#textinput").keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value.indexOf("24004") > -1) {
    $('#textinput2').val("My new value");
  }
  if (value.indexOf("24005") > -1) {
    $('#textinput2').val("My new value");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="listname" id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" value="" required />
<datalist id="listname">
    <option value="24004 - Name1 - Street1 - Place1">
    <option value="24005 - Name2 - Street2 - Place2">
    <option value="24006 - Name3 - Street3 - Place3">
</datalist>

<input id="textinput2" name="textinput2" type="text" value="" required />
```

Comment: Super many thanks, I have now understood how the > -1 works

Comment: @Ahmet No problem, if it solved your problem please consider marking it as answered so others know what solved your problem